# Can intellij plugins have a window that itself has tabs?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

New to intellij plugin development.

It's *hard* to find an open source codebase on github short of downloading all the plugins, which isn't relaly feasible. None of their plugin pages ever has a screen shot of what the plugin looks like - oh well.

Simple enough question, can an intellij plugin with a ui window have, within that window, it's own tabs? Is there any short sample code for this, or a link to a github account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IntelliJ plugin can have any UI it wants; there are no limitations.

If by "UI window" you mean a toolwindow (a panel on the side of the screen), you can use `toolWindow.getContentManager().addContent()` to create tabs in that toolwindow. You can search for usages of this method in the IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition codebase to find plenty of examples of its use.

Comment: hey, where is this codebase? looking on guthub yields no results for me for that term